# How to fix this error when playing media in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, media-player, mp4

I am coding a media player that is suppose to display a MP4 folder. The MP4 will display in a panel, and will be received from a `TOpenDialog` component. But, I get an error like this:

> Cannot determine the device type from the given filename extension.

Is there any way to fix this?

Here is part of the code that will play the media:

```pascal
if OpVideo.execute then
begin
  Opvideo.InitialDir := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName);
  TimerVideo.Enabled := false;
  medPLayer.Open;
  medPlayer.FileName := Opvideo.FileName;

  medPLayer.Display := PnlDisplay;
  medPLayer.DisplayRect :=   pnlDisplay.clientrect;
  TrackLengthBar.Max := medPLayer.TrackLength[1];
  TimerVideo.Enabled := true;
end;
```

Hope this is enough info to provide help to my cause!

Comment: VCL `TMediaPlye`r is quite limited on what file types it can play. And as far as I know it doesn't have support for any moder video file at all. So no *.mp4, *.mkv, *.ogg, etc. even when you have suitable codecs installed on your computer. FMX `TMediaPlayer` on the other hand can play most modern video files if proper codes are installed on computer. But for me the picture always ends up garbled as if wasn't rendered properly.

Answer (score 1):

The error is given because the media player is asked to open before it has any file name (same error would also be given if the file type is unknown for the MP).

The correct sequence is as follows:

```
uses System.IOUtils;  // for TPath

OpenDialog1.InitialDir := TPath.GetDocumentsPath;
if OpenDialog1.Execute() then // returns false if user cancels, true otherwise
begin
  MediaPlayer1.FileName := OpenDialog1.FileName;  // first set filename to play
  MediaPLayer1.Open;                              // then open
  MediaPlayer1.Play;                              // then play
  // following two settings would normally be set already at form creation
  MediaPlayer1.Display := Panel1;
  MediaPLayer1.DisplayRect := Panel1.ClientRect;
  ... trackbar settings ...
end;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! And that file would be the exact path in explorer? Would there be anyway to make it universal to work on any pc that the program is loaded on? And I also seem to get a error now that says there was an a problem in initializing the mci?

Comment: Sorry, I should not have left `InitialDir` as I tested the code. You can leave it empty, or set it to something generic like `Documents`. For the error what specific error message? And on which line when you single step through the code ( with F8)?

Comment: I have the same problem with `.mp4` files. Enter "[delphi] mp4" (without the quotes) in the Stack Overflow search box and you will find several questions and answers. I will try some of them tomorrow.

Comment: Exact error message is raised exception class EMCIDeviceError with message 'A problem occurred in initialising MCI.'. The file in question is mp4 too I have been trying to see some alternatives to try get it to work but no success so far.

Comment: This error mention in my previous comment happens the moment I select the mp4 file upon pressing the button to activate the code.Also the IntialDir how would you use documents for that?